# unable to locate package "software-properties-common" docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to create an ubuntu focal image using docker file. I have this line in my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal AS systemdependencies 

RUN    apt update \
&& apt --yes upgrade \
&& apt --yes install software-properties-common \
&& add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Here is the error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
The command '/bin/sh -c apt --yes install software-properties-common' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

anyy idea?

Comment: Did you `apt-get update` prior to running the above command?

Comment: yes! I did that, updated the question

Comment: Can you update your question to include a complete `Dockerfile` that reproduces the problem? If I take your `RUN` command and add it to a `Dockerfile` that starts with `FROM ubuntu:focal`, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: it is in my docker file:
FROM ubuntu:focal AS systemdependencies

Comment: please add that as an edit to your question not in a comment.

Comment: can you please give me a hint instead?? if you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error using the Dockerfile from your question. Do you continue to experience the same problem if you first `docker pull ubuntu:focal` to ensure your local image is up-to-date? Do you get this error using exactly the Dockerfile you've shown in your question?

Comment: The Dockerfile in question is building fine for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

If there are resolution errors (which then disappear) during apt-update, such as

```
 => => # Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                                 
 => => #   Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'    
  => => # Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                           
 => => #   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

you can try configuring dns or using host network, i.e.
`docker build --network=host`

Excellent article about this:
https://medium.com/@faithfulanere/solved-docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-anything-9ea4dfdcdcf2

Comment: This fixed for in ubuntu 22 :thumbsup